# Ledi Sayadaw Raised a Few Points in Contrary to the Commentaries. What are They?

Tags: controversy

Initially some of the writings of Ledi Sayadaw were considered to be controversial and they differed from the commentaries. What were the points that differed?

Comment: Can you provide a source for your statement of controversy?

Comment: "The Great War of the Commentaries: Ledi Sayadaw’s Abhidhamma Controversy" by Erik Braun is one source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the controversies and many others were concerned with attribution of the work of Abhidhamma and that some books contained errors

"4. Paramatthadipani-Tika, "The Elucidation of the Ultimate Meaning," by
Ledi Sayadaw. Ledi Sayadaw of Burma (1846-1923) was one of the greatest
scholar-monks and meditation masters of the Theravada tradition in recent
times. He was the author of over seventy manuals on different aspects of
Theravada Buddhism, including philosophy, ethics, meditation practice, and
Pali grammar. His tika created a sensation in the field of Abhidhamma
studies because he pointed out 325 places in the esteemed Vibhavini-tika
where he alleged that errors and misinterpretations had occurred, though
his criticisms also set off a reaction in defense of the older work."

[Excerpts of some of the controversies](http://www.abhidhamma.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=440)